# TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__' Error

Tags: python

Im trying to play this game and i open all the .Bat files and the virtual .Bat file says this.....

```
  File "toontown\toonbase\ToonBase.py", line 78, in __init__
    res = ratios[nativeIndex + 1][0]
TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Can anyone help me fix this? Thank you for your Answers

thank you all for your answers, This is the code for ToonBase.py

```
width = float(res[0])
            height = float(res[1])
            ratio = round(width / height, 2)
            self.resDict.setdefault(ratio, []).append(res)
```

I also Found float a little in the code im sorry im not an expert at this.

```
 ratios = sorted(self.resDict.keys(), reverse=False)
                nativeIndex = ratios.index(self.nativeRatio)
                res = ratios[nativeIndex + 1][0]
```

This is the code that is mentioned in the previous post. Thank you again for all your answers.

Comment: Please explain how this is JavaScript.

Comment: Infact it isn't javascript but python

Comment: In order to get to the source of your error, you would need to post the code in `ToonBase.py`. But it seems that either `ratios` or `ratios[nativeIndex + 1]` is of type `float` and thus does not implement the `__getitem__` method which is used for the `[]` operator

Comment: '# Okay, we don't have any resolutions that match our screen's
                # resolutions and fit it (besides the native ratio itself, of
                # course). Let's just use the second largest ratio:
                ratios = sorted(self.resDict.keys(), reverse=False)
                nativeIndex = ratios.index(self.nativeRatio)
                res = ratios[nativeIndex + 1][0]' 
thats the code for Toonbase.py i aslo found this if this would help idk

Comment: width = float(res[0])
            height = float(res[1])
            ratio = round(width / height, 2)
            self.resDict.setdefault(ratio, []).append(res) i found the text float in the ToonBase.py File.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, going off of what code you've posted, here's what I was able to infer.

```
width = float(res[0])
height = float(res[1])
ratio = round(width / height, 2)
self.resDict.setdefault(ratio, []).append(res)
# resDict is a dictionary of float -> list
```

Then you have:

```
ratios = sorted(self.resDict.keys(), reverse=False)
# ratios is a list of resDict keys (float)
nativeIndex = ratios.index(self.nativeRatio)
res = ratios[nativeIndex + 1][0]
# ratios[nativeIndex + 1] is a resDict key (float)
```

You're attempting to index a float value.  I suspect you're trying to index the dictionary with that key instead.

```
selectedKey = ratios[nativeIndex + 1]
res = self.resDict[selectedKey][0]
```